# Using multiple namespaces in XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, marklogic

There are 2 xml document with different namespaces, e.g.

```
declare namespace ml1 = "urn:schemas-com:ml1";
declare namespace ml2 = "urn:schemas-com:ml2";
```

but with same structure.
Can I select some nodes using only these namespaces, without *? I mean something like that:

```
fn:doc($uri)/(ml1 or ml2):root
```

**Updated:**
Thanks. All suggestions work but not useful for me. Because there can be 3 or more namespaces, and xpath expression will be very large. Any suggestions?

**Conclusion:**
Thanks for the answers. I agree with @MichaelKay that I should process all xml all documents. Problem is solved.

Comment: I'd say that the solution from Dimitre {`doc($uri)/(ml1:root|ml2:root)`} is pretty much as short as possible. But perhaps you can elaborate on why the solutions don't work for you. PS: perhaps add coments to solutions themselves for better feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One possible expression is**:

```
  doc($uri)/(ml1:root|ml2:root)
```

**Another is**:

```
  doc($uri)/*[self::ml1:root or self::ml2:root]
```

**In case there can be an unlimited number of prefixes of the form `"mlNNNNN""`, use:**

```
  doc($uri)/*[matches(substring-before(name(), ':'), '^ml\d+')]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use predicates

```
fn:doc($uri)/*[local-name() = "root" and (namespace-uri() = "urn:schemas-com:ml1" or namespace-uri() = "urn:schemas-com:ml2")]
```

If your namespace URIs all have a common prefix (as the examples you've supplied suggest) then you can use a construction like

```
..../*[starts-with(namespace-uri(), "urn:schemas-com:") ...]
```

If you have a number of namespaces and you can list them all in another XML file:

```
<namespaces>
  <uri>urn:schemas-com:ml1</uri>
  <uri>urn:schemas-com:ml2</uri>
  <!-- ... -->
</namespaces>
```

and then the predicate

```
*[namespace-uri() = fn:doc("namespaces.xml")/namespaces/uri]
```

would be true if the namespace URI of the node being tested matches *any* of the namespaces listed in `namespaces.xml`.

Comment: This can be shortened to `fn:doc($uri)/*[local-name() = "root" and namespace-uri() = ("urn:schemas-com:ml1", "urn:schemas-com:ml2")]` when using XPath 2.0..

Answer (score 2):

```
let $qnames :=
  for $ns in ("urn:schemas-com:ml1", "urn:schemas-com:ml2")
  return QName($ns, 'root')
return doc($uri)/*[node-name(.) = $qnames]
```

The `node-name` lookup should use the indexes.

Or you could use string-manipulation to build a path, then call `xdmp:unpath` to evaluate it: http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/apidoc/ExsltBuiltins.xml&category=Extension&function=xdmp:unpath

Answer (score 2):

The best solution when you have this problem is to start by normalizing the namespaces: that is, do a transformation so that all the documents are in a common format, and then apply the XPath expression to the normalized form.